# Query data binding with repeated values on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, data-binding

Suppose I have a query like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE table.a = 23
AND table.b = 23
AND (23 - table.c)/23 > 0.2
```

This may not have any sense because it is just an example. My real query is much bigger than this one. As you can see, all the values to be binded are equals.

So, how can I use CodeIgniter data binding for this query if all `?` are the same data?

Repeting values like this on an array looks strange on code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *"
       ." FROM table"
       ." WHERE table.a = ?"
       ." AND table.b = ?"
       ." AND (? - table.c)/? > 0.2";

$this->db->query($sql, array(23, 23, 23, 23);
```

Comment: Might not work, but try giving it a shot: https://pastebin.com/vRatQWHE

Comment: Codeigniter doesn't seem to support named bindings. I don't really see a problem with repeating the values so much.

Comment: I read in another answer that a guy had to change the codeigniter source code in the database class in order to make it accept named bindings.

Comment: Maybe you can create your own function that will generate the query with the parameters and then you pass it to codeigniter

Comment: `$this->db->query(yourFunctionName($sql, array(23, 23, 23, 23));`

Comment: I don't think it is worth to change codeigniter source code. I will try a function like you said. It appears to be the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter doesn't seem to provide named bindings, so a workaround for when all the values are the same would be to use [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php):

```
array_fill(0, 5, 23);
```

Will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 23
    [1] => 23
    [2] => 23
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 23
)
```